# Restart after verbal offence against referee by substitute off the field while the ball is in play

Tags: rules, football

The ball is in play. A substitute, off the field of play in their technical area, either engages in dissent, or uses offensive, insulting and/or abusive language against the referee. The referee stops play, and either cautions or sends off the substitute (depending on which of the above offences was committed).

How is play restarted and where does the restart take place?

Comment: The reason I'm asking this question, is because while many scenarios are covered in the current Laws (i.e. sub commits offence against player, player commits offence against sub), none of them cover this specific case.

Comment: This would be a drop ball, surely, for not having given a kick or throw, but stopping play to handle "any other situation"?

Comment: @Nij - you would think so. That's what I would have done had it happened in a game I was refereeing. However, after seeing this answer http://asktheref.com/Soccer%20Rules/Question/31617/ on what is a fairly reputable Q + A site, that details it is an indirect free kick restart if a substitute commits misconduct off the field of play, I'm suddenly not so sure. I'll have a go at self-answering if I don't get an answer that details why it is a dropped ball within the next day or so.

Comment: Seems they are saying a drop ball if the substitute is off the field, IFK if they are on it (for the separate offence  entry without permission) and appropriate caution/dismissal.

Comment: No, in point c) (which is a substitute committing an offence off the field of play), both answers state indirect free kick.

Comment: Point c) is "against another sub or team official on the match sheet, same team or not". So it is not against the referee, which must fall under point d) " anybody else, on or off the field" as the only option that covers them from the four provided.

Comment: I'm not really satisfied with that reasoning, as the referee is not an outside agent for the purposes of [Law 12.4](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/restart-of-play-after-fouls-and-misconduct), which groups substitutes, substituted players, team officials and match officials (e.g. the referee) together for most outlined restarts. I think it's best I have a go at self-answering this question and any comments on it can be raised there.

Comment: None of them cover it because there is absolutely no reason for the official to stop play at that point.  Substitute isn't going anywhere, so the referee can wait until action stops (or at least goes idle), administer punishment, and then continue where it was (with an indirect kick for the team that had the ball) or the appropriate re-start, if he waited until there was a stoppage.

Comment: Play should always be stopped immediately for cautionable or sending-off offences committed by anyone, unless an appropriate advantage can be played (for sending-off offences, this should be an obvious goalscoring opportunity - see [Practical Guidelines for Match Officials](http://static-3eb8.kxcdn.com/assets/documents/LotG2017/LotG_17_18_EN_Guidelines.pdf) (pdf) p. 194). The only exception to this is a goalkeeper change without permission as outlined in Law 3.

Comment: However, if you have a reference to support the "indirect free kick for the team that has the ball" restart (which I believe is a US high school-only rule), you should definitely write an answer with the reference and I'll consider accepting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Correction (the previous answer was incorrect, stating dropped ball was the correct restart)*:

This question was posed to IFAB in an email dated Thursday, 27th July 2017. As I did not ask permission to post the email thread in full, only an excerpt containing the pertinent information is provided:

> In the scenario you mention the correct restart is an IDFK *(indirect free kick - editor's note)* on the boundary line nearest to where the verbal offence occurred - see LotG 2017/18, page 105

IFAB has indicated that it will publish Law queries on their website in the near future. If this question and answer appears on their website, I will update this answer to refer there instead so it can be validated by other users.

Comment: The answer is correct, since this rule has changed during the last couple of years, before the change the rules stated a restart by a dropped ball.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment. So a different and possibly correct answer although my first instinct was a dropped ball.

But reading the third main bullet in Law 12 of @studro 's self answer this appears to be a direct free kick. Ball is in play, the offence is made by one of the persons listed, outside the field of play. Law 12 states a direct free kick. The language is definitely not precise but whether the official is inside the lines or outside should not really matter in this case. In my opinion the rule refers to the position of the offending player / team official and thus implies a direct free kick. If it had happened yesterday I would have resumed with a dropped ball. Now I'm not sure.

Comment: My reading is that "outside the field of play" applies to "opposing player or match official", not to the substitute committing the offence. Either way, I don't see how this can be a direct free kick offence, as "dissent ... offensive, insulting or abusive language ... or other verbal offences" is prescribed as an indirect free kick offence in [12.2](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/indirect-free-kick).

Comment: If they meant the target of the offence being inside the field of play, then that phrase would come **after** the clause dealing with the target. Instead the phrase comes after the offender, but **before** the clause and preposition dealing with the target and relationship to the offender. We see this difference occur with Law 12, section 4. The phrase then applies to the offender, which does not match this situation. Not a DFK. -1.

Comment: It remains vague and my instinct remains a dropped ball. But the wording still appears to imply that the player / substitute is outside the field of play. How can a referee be outside the field of play? Why downvote an honest opinion?

Comment: I personally wouldn't upvote this answer, as it's not backed by a reference, but I wouldn't downvote it either, as it's an answer based on the spirit of the game, which is an important concept as outlined in [Law 5, Section 2, Paragraph 1](http://theifab.com/laws/the-referee/chapters/decisions-of-the-referee). Unfortunately, I don't think the Laws are flexible enough here to allow you to award a free kick for something that's not listed as a free kick offence.

Comment: BTW, I'm still looking for a definitive reference for this. If I can't find one, I'll probably end up sending a [law enquiry](http://theifab.com/contact) to IFAB.